# sqoop export failed after successful map

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, sqoop

```
1.sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hduser_db --username hduser 
    --password hduser --table export --export-dir /user/hive/warehouse/three --
fields-terminated-by ','

17/09/13 14:10:45 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
17/09/13 14:10:50 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
17/09/13 14:10:51 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1505199140014_0033 failed with 
state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1505199140014_0033_m_000000
ob failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0

2.17/09/13 14:10:51 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 8
```

> Job Counters
>                   Failed map tasks=1
>                   Launched map tasks=1
>                   Rack-local map tasks=1
>                   Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=2947
>                   Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
>                   Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=2947
>                   Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=2947
>                   Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=3017728
>       17/09/13 14:10:51 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group FileSystemCounters is 
>       deprecate
>       17/09/13 14:10:51 INFO mapreduce.ExportJobBase: Transferred 0 bytes in 
>       14.8875 s
>       17/09/13 14:10:51 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group 
>       org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$C
>       17/09/13 14:10:51 INFO mapreduce.ExportJobBase: Exported 0 records.
>       17/09/13 14:10:51 ERROR tool.ExportTool: Error during export:
>       Export job failed!
>           at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ExportJobBase.runExport(ExportJobBase.java
>           at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.exportTable(SqlManager.java:931)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.exportTable(ExportTool.java:80)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.run(ExportTool.java:99)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:243)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:252)

Answer (score 0):

While running export command-
Below steps have to be taken care.

1. Datatypes, column names between source(HDFS data) and destination(table on rdbms) should match.
2. we should specify all column names in the --columns parameter.

Eg:

sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hduser_db 
--username hduser 
--password hduser 
--table export 
--export-dir /user/hive/warehouse/three 
--fields-terminated-by ',' 
--columns "column1,column2,...." ;